# How to find the index of the first day of the week in a specified month?

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar

I want to find a way to calculate the index of the first day of the week in a specified month. The code below is what I am starting with:

```
public static int getFirstDayOfWeekInMonth(String month, int year)
    return ;
```

For example, if the variable month = October, and year = 2019, the return should be 1, since the first day of week of October is Tuesday (Mon = 0, Tue = 1, Wed = 2...).

I want to create a formula that is similar to this, but not with January being 13 and February being 14: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Implementation_in_software

Comment: Since that Wikipedia page describes what you need to do, I assume you are having a problem translating a month name to a number between 3 and 14, right?

Comment: Don’t base your code off an algorithm from Wikipedia. The functionality is built in, use that. [The `LocalDate` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) gives you what you need.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does the month renumbering in Zeller's formula bother you so much? It's easy enough to do, and it works perfectly. (The renumbering is intended to put the leap day at the end of the year, which makes computations much easier.)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);

public static DayOfWeek getFirstDayOfWeekInMonth(String month, int year) {
    Month m = Month.from(monthFormatter.parse(month));
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = LocalDate.of(year, m, 1);
    return firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek();
}
```

My imports are:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfTheWeek = getFirstDayOfWeekInMonth("October", 2019);
    System.out.println("First day of week of October 2019 is " + firstDayOfTheWeek);
```

Output is:

> First day of week of October 2019 is TUESDAY

I am happy to give you a `DayOfWeek` enum rather than a numerical index. It’s much more programmer friendly (and just as efficient). In other words, I see no reason why you should want a numerical index, but if you insist:

```
    int dowIndex = firstDayOfTheWeek.getValue();
    System.out.println("Index is " + dowIndex);
```

> Index is 2

`DayOfWeek` numbers the days from 1 = Monday through 7 = Sunday. This numbering agrees with ISO 8601, the international standard, and to avoid confusion, I recommend you follow it too. If you do insist on a 0-based index, just subtract 1.

**Edit:**

> How can I change the code so that it accepts a lower-case input, like
>   "sep"? … Just the abbreviation would be good for now.

The following version of the formatter accepts a month abbreviation (sep) rather than a full month name (september) and doesn’t care about case:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("MMM")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Use it en lieu of the one above. Trying the method out with this change:

```
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfTheWeek = getFirstDayOfWeekInMonth("sep", 2019);
    System.out.println("First day of week of sep 2019 is " + firstDayOfTheWeek);
```

> ```
> First day of week of sep 2019 is SUNDAY
> Index is 7
> ```

**Further edit:**

> If I want to accept both the full month name and the abbreviation, but
>   also case-insensitive, how would I do that?

```
private static DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .appendPattern("[MMMM][MMM]")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

In the format pattern square brackets enclose optional parts. `MMMM` is for full month name, so Java first tries to parse one (e.g., september). No matter if successful or not, it then tries to parse an abbreviation ( `MMM`, sep). If just one of the attempts is successful, it’s got a month, and the rest works as before.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: In addition, is there any way to achieve this while not changing the code that I used? Meaning that getFirstDayOfWeekInMonth returns an int value.

Comment: If I want to accept both the full month name and the abbreviation, but also case-insensitive, how would I do that?